# Tex capacity exceeded for label size

Tags: pgfplots

When I want to modify the ylabel size via `tick label style={font=\Large}`, I get the following error message (without the ylabel size, the compilation is ok) :

```
Package pgfplots notification 'compat/show suggested version=true': document ha
s been generated with the most recent feature set (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}).

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=10000].
\@nomath ...e \@font@warning {Command \noexpand #1
                                                  invalid in math mode}\fi 
l.58     ]
          
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 31676 strings out of 411566
 808668 string characters out of 2820184
 1852973 words of memory out of 3000000
 51354 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 512295 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 10000i,2n,14993p,7531b,715s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

My code :

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgf-spectra}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
% Preamble: 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{
  function sinc2(\x) {
    if  abs(\x) < .001 then { % (|x| < .001) ~ (x = 0)
      return 1;
    } else {
      return (sin(\x r)/\x)*(sin(\x r)/\x);
    };
  };
}

\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={
    axis lines=middle,
    grid=both,
    minor tick num=1,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
    xtick={-3*pi, -2*pi, -pi, pi, 2*pi, 3*pi},
    xticklabels={$-3\frac{\lambda D\pi}{a}$, $-2\frac{\lambda D\pi}{a}$,  $-\frac{\lambda D\pi}{a}$,$\frac{\lambda D\pi}{a}$,  $2\frac{\lambda D\pi}{a}$, $3\frac{\lambda D\pi}{a}$},
                    label style={font=\tiny},
                    tick label style={font=\Large}  
                                        ytick=\empty
                    }}

%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (-3,0) rectangle (3,6);
    \fill [white] (-0.05,1) rectangle (0.05,5);

\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
\draw (-3.5,0) rectangle (3.5,6);
\fill [red] (0,3) ellipse (1 and 0.2);
\fill [red] (1.6,3) ellipse (0.5 and 0.15);
\fill [red] (2.7,3) ellipse (0.5 and 0.13);
\fill [red] (-1.6,3) ellipse (0.5 and 0.15);
\fill [red] (-2.7,3) ellipse (0.5 and 0.13);

   % \fill [white] (-0.05,1) rectangle (0.05,5);
    
\end{scope}

\begin{axis}[xshift=11cm,
        width=20cm,
        height=8cm
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-4*pi:4*pi,samples=200,red] {sinc2(x))};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're missing a comma after `{font=\Large}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a comma after `{font=\Large}`.

On the other hand, I believe you should use `\dfrac` (need `amsmath`) instead of `\Large`.

Compare the output

#### with `\dfrac` in the tick labels

[image]

#### With `font=\Large` and `\frac`

[image]

#### fixed code (with `\Large` and `\frac`)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

% Preamble: 
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\tikzmath{
  function sinc2(\x) {
    if  abs(\x) < .001 then { % (|x| < .001) ~ (x = 0)
      return 1;
    } else {
      return (sin(\x r)/\x)*(sin(\x r)/\x);
    };
  };
}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  every axis/.append style={
    axis lines=middle,
    grid=both,
    minor tick num=1,
    grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
    major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!50},
    xtick={-3*pi, -2*pi, -pi, pi, 2*pi, 3*pi},
    xticklabels={
      $-3\frac{\lambda D\pi}{a}$,
      $-2\frac{\lambda D\pi}{a}$,
      $-\frac{\lambda D\pi}{a}$,
      $\frac{\lambda D\pi}{a}$,
      $2\frac{\lambda D\pi}{a}$,
      $3\frac{\lambda D\pi}{a}$,
    },
    label style={font=\tiny},
    tick label style={font=\Large},
    ytick=\empty,
  }
}

%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------------------------
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill (-3,0) rectangle (3,6);
    \fill [white] (-0.05,1) rectangle (0.05,5);

\begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
\draw (-3.5,0) rectangle (3.5,6);
\fill [red] (0,3) ellipse (1 and 0.2);
\fill [red] (1.6,3) ellipse (0.5 and 0.15);
\fill [red] (2.7,3) ellipse (0.5 and 0.13);
\fill [red] (-1.6,3) ellipse (0.5 and 0.15);
\fill [red] (-2.7,3) ellipse (0.5 and 0.13);

   % \fill [white] (-0.05,1) rectangle (0.05,5);
    
\end{scope}

\begin{axis}[xshift=11cm,
        width=20cm,
        height=8cm
    ]
    \addplot[domain=-4*pi:4*pi,samples=200,red] {sinc2(x))};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have the habit of specifying a single option per line, with less generous indentation. This way it's easier to comment one option. Always use a comma after any option, so you don't risk to forget one in case you add another one (likely the cause of the problem).

I removed all the inessential packages. Do you really use both PSTricks and PGFplots?